# ANT fileset includes in all filesystem

Tags: java, ant

I want to create a fileset that contains the jdk classpath. The problem is that fileset is composed with files in all of the filesystem, not in a specific directory.
For example:

```
jdk.classpath.includes = ${jdk.home}/lib/**/*.jar, \
                         ${jdk.home}/../Classes/**/*.jar, \
                         /Library/Java/Extensions/**/*.jar, \
                         /System/Library/Java/Support/Deploy.bundle/Contents/Resources/Java/**/*.jar
```

So, when i create the fileset i need to do not specify the dir, or to specify the filesystem root directory, like:

```
<fileset dir="INeedFileSystemRootDirectory" includes="${jdk.classpath.includes}"/>
```

How can this be accomplished?
(I didn't find a built-in property to get the filesystem root)

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can make your fileset be composed of many  tags, each with a different path:

example:

```
  <fileset dir="${INeedFileSystemRootDirectory}">
    <include name="${jdk.home}/lib/**/*.jar"/>
    <include name="${jdk.home}/../Classes/**/*.jar"/>
     ...
  </fileset>
```

Documentation and more examples [here](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/fileset.html).

Comment: I found that is not possible to use absolute paths in fileset.  I used the relative path to the root filesystem path in includes, and in the fileset dir I used the root filesystem path